# Azure Traffic Manager External Endpoint - CNAME - Website Account Suspended

Tags: azure, dns, azure-traffic-manager

I have a web server on -premises  and have configured the Azure Traffic Manager with external endpoint that points to the public IP address of the web server.

The web server's external DNS is www..com. As per the Microsoft Documentation i have added the traffic manager DNS Name : http://.trafficmanager.net as a CNAME record to www..com.The monitoring status on the Traffic Manager reports that the on-premises server endpoint is healthy.

The issue i am having is that now when i go to www..com, where it used to work correctly before it now reports:

"Account Suspended" and the following has been appended to the URL: /cgi-sys/suspendedpage.cgi.

Im not sure what the issue is here as it was working without the traffic manager but now it is not accessible.

Any guidance on why this is occurring would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure why it's happening, but Traffic Manager would not modify the URL. It's replying to your DNS queries, that's all. Your app (or something else) should be adding that path to the URL.

Comment: I would start with the request flow. Press F12 and check the request and response. Check if you are seeing any redirection which ends you up to that page. If you can specify the FQDN via private chat, I can test it from my end.

Answer (score 0):

As the comment from @juunas, the Traffic Manager would not modify the URL, it uses DNS to direct client requests to the most appropriate service endpoint based on a traffic-routing method and the health of the endpoints. Clients then connect to the service endpoint **directly**, **not through Traffic Manager**. Traffic Manager does not see HTTP traffic between client and server. Read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-faqs#why-am-i-seeing-an-http-error-when-using-traffic-manager) for more details.

If you see any HTTP error, it must be coming from your application. Not sure what the web app what you are using, and you may google that error for more references. Such as [“This Account Has Been Suspended” – How to Fix Website Problem?](https://webhostingmedia.net/this-account-has-been-suspended/)

Hope this could help you.